# Knockout - binding error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js

Got error in binding data in chrome, even though it was working fine in FireFox.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: contents, visible: contents().length > 0">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: ContentName"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function content(data) {
            this.ContentName = ko.observable(data.contentName);
         }
               function contentListViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.contents = ko.observableArray([]); // array of content, populated by ajax
         }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing viewmodel property names to lowercase, and names in binding, everything was fine again!

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: contents, visible: contents().length > 0">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: contentName"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function content(data) {
            this.contentName = ko.observable(data.contentName);
         }
               function contentListViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.contents = ko.observableArray([]); // array of content, populated by ajax
         }
</script>
```

Comment: The "this" is really the window object ? Why do you don't using a viewModel object ?

Comment: That object is a part of the viewmodel object, i havent pasted in the viewmodel code, I think i might have messed around a bit with terminology. 

the this. is reffering to function content, which is an object on the viewmodel.